# pickle/cloudpickle Python 3.7 in colab installed but not found

Tags: google-colaboratory, pickle, cloudpickle

On my laptop I use pickle abundantly with the routine

```
def read_pickle(source_file):
    with open(source_file, "rb") as fp:
        data = pickle.load(fp)
        fp.close()
    return data
```

When using that as

```
data = read_pickle(datafile)
```

it throws the error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numba/core/serialize.py in _unpickle__CustomPickled(serialized)
    206     Uses `NumbaPickler` to load.
    207     """
--> 208     ctor, states = loads(serialized)
    209     return _CustomPickled(ctor, states)
    210 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numba.cloudpickle'
```

However, all packages are installed. Is this a typical problem for working in colab?. I'm happy with a work around that isn't as fast/efficient etc.

thanks,

Andreas